# wifi device is not displaying in ubuntu

Tags: drivers, wireless

I just installed (dual boot) Ubuntu 16.04 (amd64) on my HP Pavilion (i3-7100, 1TB) laptop but it is not showing any available wifi device.
When I look at network in settings only network proxy is displayed and also I don't have Ethernet cable slot in my laptop.
How can I fix this problem?

`rfkill list all` displays the following result:

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

output of the command : lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.2 Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
```

Comment: Open terminal and enter `rfkill list all` and edit the question to include the results

Comment: 0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if `echo "blacklist acer-wmi" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/acer-wmi.conf` works after a reboot.  I suspect you may have other issues

To install the 4.8 kernel and firmware you will need to download
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-edge/linux-image-4.8.0-34-generic_4.8.0-34.36~16.04.1_amd64.deb

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-edge/linux-image-extra-4.8.0-34-generic_4.8.0-34.36~16.04.1_amd64.deb

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-hwe-edge/linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04-edge_4.8.0.34.6_amd64.deb

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-edge/linux-headers-4.8.0-34_4.8.0-34.36~16.04.1_all.deb

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-edge/linux-headers-4.8.0-34-generic_4.8.0-34.36~16.04.1_amd64.deb

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-hwe-edge/linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04-edge_4.8.0.34.6_amd64.deb

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta-hwe-edge/linux-generic-hwe-16.04-edge_4.8.0.34.6_amd64.deb

http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb

Transfer the files to the Ubuntu desktop and then in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb
```

With any luck they will be installed in the correct order and you will have wireless after a reboot

Comment: when i use the above command, it return   "blacklist acer-wmi"

Comment: That is normal, reboot and see if there are other issues

Comment: i am facing only this issue and nothing else..thanx

Comment: Now it is showing wireless devices, i just connect it to wired device and follow the steps (pilot6 suggest me). Thanx to you also.

Comment: So are you using Ubuntu 16.10?